# Why is `yield self` helpful?

Tags: ruby

As a Ruby newbie, it's confusing to me why it would ever be beneficial to `yield self` within a method definition. I've come across this functionality in a number of tutorials as being something that is helpful -- it makes perfect sense to me *how* this works, but I don't understand *why* you'd ever use it.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class Dog

  attr_accessor :breed

  def initialize
    @breed = "Westie"
  end

  def bark
    puts "Woof!"
    yield self if block_given?
  end

end

fido = Dog.new

fido.bark do |d|
  puts "Bark, bark, bark!"
  puts d.breed  
end
```

So yeah, via `yield self`, I now have access to the instance of the `Dog` class within the block that I am yielding too.

But, even if I don't `yield self`, I would *still* have access to that instance, right? In other words, wouldn't the code below work *exactly* the same as the code above?

```
class Dog

  attr_accessor :breed

  def initialize
    @breed = "Westie"
  end

  def bark
    puts "Woof!"
    yield
  end

end

fido = Dog.new

fido.bark do
  puts "Bark, bark, bark!"
  puts fido.breed   
end
```

Note that in the second code sample, I'm not calling `yield self`.

I'm clearly missing the utility here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example works because of the specific circumstances where you have a local variable referring to the the `Dog`. As an alternative consider what happens if using an anonymous instance:

```
Dog.new.bark do
  puts "Bark, bark, bark!"
  # what goes here?? puts ????.breed   
end
```

or maybe you want to declare your block somewhere else and pass it in e.g.

```
loud = lambda { |dog| puts "A #{dog.breed} doing some LOUD YAPPING" }

puts d.bark(&loud)
```

so essentially setting up with `yield self` gives flexibility in how your code can be used.

Comment: Ah, I didn't consider `yield self` within the context of an anonymous instance -- the utility there makes sense to me. Thanks! Your second example is less obvious to me, though likely because I'm still too new to Ruby. I'll have to do a bit more thinking there. :) Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Your examples are pretty simple, and there's no obvious use for `yield self` in them.

There are cases when it *is* useful though, the same way that [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) is useful: It allows you to define and use a value without introducing a variable in the local scope.

A (admittedly very contrived) example would be:

```
Dog.new.bark do |d|
  puts d.breed
end
```